# Why isnt my right div floating inline with the rest?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs on my page for a gallery page im building, I need to center the 'center' div so that its central on any screen with a div floating left and one right either side of it. The left and center divs seems to work fine and are inline with each other but my right floating div is positioned lower down then the other 2.

Why is this happening?

HTML

```
<div id="left">
IM ON THE LEFT  
</div>


<div id="middle">
I AM IN THE MIDDLE
</div>

<div id="right">
THIS IS ON THE RIGHT
</div>
```

CSS

```
#left{
float:left;
position:relative;
width: 150px;

}

#middle{
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 150px;
position: relative;

}


#right{
float:right;
width: 150px;
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `position:` and `float:` on the same element... it creates a conflict... just use one or the other.

Comment: It is position relative which is fine, the box could be shifted from that position or it may be there for absolutely position child elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a possible corection

```
#left{
float:left;
position:relative;
width: 150px;
display: inline-block;
}

#middle{
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 150px;
position: relative;

}


#right{
float:right;
width: 150px;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}
```

try to see if it orks for you...

Answer (score 2):

It happens because `#middle` is a block level element and does not float. This creates a new line, and your float right will start on the next line. If you float your middle block to the left it should work just fine, provided that there is enough space. Alternatively, you could place your `#right`-div at the top of the HTML. This way it will be floated right, then `#left` will be floated left, and `#middle` will stay in the normal document flow, i.e. in the middle if there is room.

Answer (score 1):

<s>In your CSS `.left` add</s>

```
display:inline-block;
```

Same for `.right`

EDIT:

Here a jsFiddle that works : http://jsfiddle.net/LwUqF/

Comment: The OP does not have `.left` or `.right` **classes** in his CSS.

Answer (score 1):

maybe there is no space for the last div to float where it is supposed to float.

maybe you can reorder your html, so the right column comes before the center column.

maybe you can do this:

```
#left {
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
}
#center {
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
}
#right {
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
}
```

Comment: This does appear to be the "easiest" solution, avoids using inline-blocks which will break in IE. I made an example: http://jsfiddle.net/chricholson/yuuUM/16/. There is still an interesting issue (which is the cause of your problem) in that if you look at where the margins are stretching (use a tool like Firebug), they overlap the divs either side. It works but I wonder if in other browsers this would break.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have specified `#middle` as `display:block` this means that this div will fill the rest of the container, and therefore pushing the `#right` div below it. Change `#middle` to `display:inline-block` and you get the desired result.

See http://jsfiddle.net/xm33e/

EDIT: Or what PatrikAkerstrand said...

Comment: That seems to work at getting rid of the gap at the top thanks but the middle div is floating left and not central, is there a way of centering it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485936/why-isnt-my-right-div-floating-inline-with-the-rest/7486087#7486087 should solve your issue

Comment: You can add a container div that has `text-align:center` this will put the middle div in the center, but might also center the text in the middle div. You can add `text-align: left` to the middle div and that should align it as you like. See http://jsfiddle.net/xm33e/1/

Answer (score 0):

You only asked for the reason.

The reason was explained well by anothershrubery.

Still a solution:

You want the 'middle' `div` in the center position, so I'llassume you have an idea of the total page width and widths of the three `div`'s.

Keep the 'left' and 'middle' `div`'s under a `div`, float it to left.

'right ' `div` will remain as it is.